# Run shell command several times, based on number of vars given in getopts

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run a command n number of times, depending on how many arguments were given to the shell, using the `getopts` function.

Here's the contents of `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "i" flag
do
  case "$flag" in
    i) name="$OPTARG";;
  esac
done
echo $name
```

I would like the `echo` command to run as many times as names are given. For example if I run `./script.sh -i One, Two, Three, Four` I would like the script to run `echo` 4 times and print the names to the shell.

Comment: Make `name` an array and append the options to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you give a *single* comma-delimited word as the argument to `-i`, then simply split it on the comma (note: requires `bash` due to the use of an array and the `-a` option to `read`).

```
while getopts "i:" flag
do
  case "$flag" in
    i) IFS=, read -a names <<< "$OPTARG";;
  esac
done

printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}"
```

Then the following should work:

```
$ ./script.sh -i One,Two,Three,Four
One
Two
Three
Four
```

`getopts` isn't really designed to handle an arbitrary number of arguments to an option.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't look closely at the `getopts` command copied from the question.

Comment: Your example works great. What if I wanted something like `cp file1.txt /path/to/$names/pictures`? `$names` being several different names given to the shell. I tried several things based on your code but couldn't get it to work...

Comment: In general, you can't simply put an array into an argument like that. You would want to run `cp` separately for each element: `for n in "${names[@]}"; do cp file1.txt "/path/to/$n/pictures"; done`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

if
  [[ "$1" = -i ]]
then
  shift
  for arg in "$@"
  do
    echo "$arg"
  done
fi
```

Maybe it does not work in your specific case depending on other options you need to handle, but I lack information to be sure.